# Will this harm system performance after the program is closed?

Tags: c#, performance

So let's say a computer that does nothing but run this program has 500 power. When it runs it, it goes down to 450. When it the program is closed, will it go back to 500? Code:

```
bool shouldCheck = true;
    string word = "hndxgfhesufyhsukj";
    string name = "NAME OF PROGRAM HERE";
    bool updates = false;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (shouldCheck == true)
        {
            var url = "MYURL";
            var client = new WebClient();
            using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string downloadedString;
                while ((downloadedString = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (downloadedString == word)
                    {
                        updates = true;
                        this.Hide();
                        Form1 form2 = new Form1();
                        form2.Show();
                        MessageBox.Show("There's no updates, and the full program has opened! Enjoy!", name, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        client.Dispose();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("There is an update! Downloading now!", name, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        url = "MYURL";
                        var web = new WebBrowser();
                        web.Navigate(url);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This runs fine, but does it harm performance after the program has closed? By closed, I mean the update has been checked for, the new form opened, and closed using the red X button.

Comment: @ByronWhitlock - I think he is afraid it will get over 9000!

Comment: I'm using 500 power as a reference so I can get my point across. There's no actual power.

Comment: your "using" block will dispose of your object correctly, releasing resources.

Comment: @chipperyman573: Using a unit of measurement that makes absolutely no sense is not helpful. Simply ask if any resources used by the application will be reclaimed by the OS when it exits.

Comment: @everyone - who cares? maybe the poor guy has bad English, we all understand what he is talking about... let it go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, it should go back to full power. You can check in task manager to make sure your program has closed correctly. If it is gone it would be hard pressed to continue to have a performance impact on your machine. One thing you need to look out for is if the form is closed but the application is still running in the background. If it is it will be listed in task manager.

Answer (score 1):

If you create threads, be sure to set them as background threads. That way if you forget to close them manually, when your program exits they will terminate. Otherwise your program will keep running.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx

You should also correctly (and nicely) stop any threads you do start, to be sure that all resources are freed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A small side note if you are ever using threading you must add a thread stop either to the closing function or in the thread itself to look for closing and end itself. I ran into an issue a while back of one of my threads not closing properly and sucking resources from the computer until it was restarted.